# Add fragment and update actionbar title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I know that question about refreshing actionbar title has already been answered.
But my problem is quiet different.

I use fragments with **add** method and not with **replace** method for some reasons. So previous fragment are not destroy and when back, previous fragment aren't not recreating.

This is my configuration :

Fragment A with title "FragA" > Fragment B with title "FragB"

When I go back to Fragment A from Fragment B the actionbar title should be "FragA" but it stay "FragB".
The problem is with **add** method Fragment A is not recreating and I didn't find event to refresh it.

The only simple solution I found for now is :

1- fragB.OnResume : save previous action bar title

2- fragB.OnDestroyView : restore previous actionbar title

With this solution, the result is ok, but I found this solution is not very clean. Is there a better way to refresh actionbartitle using **add** method with fragments ?

Comment: are you using the hardware back button to go back to fragA?

Comment: Yes, I use back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **override** your `onBackPressed` of your activity and each time you pressed it you then get the name of the fragment from the **backstack** to know which fragment you current at.

**sample:**

```
  @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    int framentCount = this.getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if(framentCount != 0)
    {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(framentCount-1);
        String str=backEntry.getName(); //the tag of the fragment
        if(str.equals("fragA"))
            //set the actionbar title to FragA
        else if(str.equals("fragB"))
            //set the actionbar title to FragB
    }

     FragA myFragA = (FragA)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENTA_A_TAG");
     if (myFragA.isVisible()) {
           //action bar.title="title first fragment"
     }
   }
```

Now to know which fragment is which you need to put a tag to your fragment when you add / replace it to the backstack. Also make sure that you call `addToBackStack` to put the fragments to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
FragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

Comment: This solution is ok, but there is again one problem. The first fragment from my current activity is not added to the back stack. So when I'm back to the first one, the title is not refresh. First fragment depends on the user's choice from the drawer, so I can't just write code : else action bar.title="title first fragment"

Comment: @gduh you can just find the fragment instead if it is not in your backstack. SEE EDIT ABOVE>

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm just testing, finally it's ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call the below line of code in all your fragments onResume() callback. you wouldnt need to save the title.

```
((YourFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(YOUR_TITLE);
```

it should help.

Comment: This don't solve my problem since fragA.onResume is not called when I press back button from fragB.

Answer (score 0):

Put a public static string called tag on your fragments, then use this where the tag is. More maintainability.

Why - This means if you want to change the tag, you only have to change it in one place, less refactoring. (Its used also on add, replace functions - see Rod's answer if confused)

My implementation of the solution is similar to how Rod solved the issue in his edited answer except a lot less code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    try {
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragA.tag) != null) {
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragA.tag).isVisible()) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.FragA_title);
            }
        }

        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragB.tag) != null) {
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragB.tag).isVisible()) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.FragB_title);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

eg of static tag use

```
FragmentTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, FragA.tag)
```

Answer (score -1):

@Override
    public void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
   }
Override the onStop() method in your current fragment, and gives the title name of your previous fragment.